# colorAccessor in dc.js barChart

Tags: colors, d3.js, dc.js

I defined the color scheme of my barChart as follows :

```
var colorChoice = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["negative","positive","test"])
                                    .range(["#FF0000","#00FF00","#FFFF00"]);

myBarChart
    .colors(colorChoice)
    .colorAccessor(function(d) {
            if (+d.data.value>0) {
                console.log("positive");
                return("positive");
            } else {
                console.log("negative");
                return("negative");
            }
        });
```

But what happens when I `renderAll()` is that all bars are of the color of the first item of my `colorChoice.domain()` (so in that case `#FF0000`).

I tried switching the two first values in the domain and it is always the first one that is used.

I also verified that my `colorAccessor` function outputs values that should be correctly interpreted by `colorChoice. (cf console log below)

```
3 negative metrics:319
3 positive metrics:316
negative metrics:319
3 positive metrics:316
negative metrics:319
positive metrics:316
2 negative metrics:319
positive metrics:316
```

All help is welcome.

Comment: Could you try to put this in a js fiddle?  You could use http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/9ELWV/ as a starting point.  My guess is that your data is somehow never evaluating as > 0.

Comment: @DJMartin You fiddle works. Thank you. I updated my question to show you the log of what the `colorAccessor` sends back in my case.

Comment: Is it fair to say that the only difference between the working jsfiddle and your problem is that the data is different?  Could you try to update the JSFiddle I provided to reproduce your problem... perhaps by changing the data to match yours?

Comment: @DJMartin Thank you for spending time on that. I am baffled. This has something to do with my source. I pointed to the online version of dc.js instead of my local one and it worked perfectly. Anyhting you have heard about that kind of issue ? My local copy is the latest version.

Comment: Hmm... not sure.  I would check whether an old cached version was being served on local.